# Sitting for the exam?

Tags: word-usage

What should we say to sit for an exam as an examinee and what should we say to take an exam from an examinee as an examiner?

I mean, if an examiner takes exam from an examinee what does he say, "I'm **taking/giving** exam and examinees are **taking/giving** exam"?

I'm confused, as one of my juniors said that examiners **give** exam and examinees **take** exam.

Comment: Yes, they were correct. What part of it confuses you? (It may be due to the fact that the equivalent of the words 'give' and 'take' in some other languages are used in an opposite manner)

Comment: Thank you. But could you please show me an authentic source on your comment.

Comment: Sure. Google is your friend. I got [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58416/125563) as one of the first few results.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. - I can see why a learner might ask for help with this. For example, [this page](https://www.wordnik.com/words/give) lists dozens of definitions for _give_, yet the words _exam_ and _test_ are nowhere to be found among those definitions.

Comment: @J.R. Actually I think it might be because, in OP's native language (presumably Indian), just like Persian and Turkish, the verbs are used in the opposite manner: The examiners "take" the exam and the examinees "give" 'em. Though the OP has to confirm, and should elaborate more on what confuses them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a teacher, you *give* an exam and the students *take* the exam. The same applies regarding subjects:

> — I'm **giving** an exam tomorrow morning to my students.
>   — We're **taking** the exam tomorrow morning to see if we can pass the subject.

Comment: Thanks all for your cordial responses those have made me clear about the topic i asked.